# Research progress in the symmetries of flat space holography

Tags: string-theory, resource-recommendations, quantum-gravity, ads-cft, holographic-principle

I was studying the papers

> [$1$] [Arjun Bagchi. The BMS/GCA correspondence](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.3354)
>
> [$2$] [Duval, C., Gibbons, G. W., & Horvathy, P. A. (2014). Conformal carroll groups. Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, 47(33), 335204.](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/47/33/335204/meta)
>
> [$3$] [Duval, C., Gibbons, G. W., & Horvathy, P. A. (2014). Conformal Carroll groups and BMS symmetry. Classical and Quantum Gravity, 31(9), 092001.](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/31/9/092001/meta)

In these paper [[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.3354)] they showed $\mathfrak{bms_3/gca_2}$ correspondences at lie algebra level of the corresponding symmetries but only in $3$ dimensional bulk space which is asymptotically flat, dual to 2 dimensional non relativistic conformal field theory.

In paper [[2](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/47/33/335204/meta), [3](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/31/9/092001/meta)], they have shown the carroll group is a *subgroup* of BMS group in any dimensions.

Query: In the recent literature is $\mathfrak{bms_{3\text{$+s$}}/gca_{2\text{$+s$}}}$ been established **in any dimensions** or is the BMS/Carroll isomorphism been successfully established
in any dimensions? If its satisfied then I request the community to post the urls of such articles.

Disclaimer: I am utterly new here so if I am incorrect in anything please correct me.

Comment: There is a new paper arXiv:2212.02360 "Hall effects in Carroll dynamics" by  L. Marsot, P. -M. Zhang, M. Chernodub, P. A. Horvathy, that may have an answer.

Comment: There is a very recent paper on the Carrollian perspective on flat space holography https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.12553, maybe it contains what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but are there any recent papers that establishes a general $\mathfrak{bms_{3\text{$+s$}}/gca_{2\text{$+s$}}}$ in any arbitrary dimensions or its still unestablished?